# What is the recommended (or a good) approach to use devcontainers with user-specific settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Apologies if this is somehow an opinion-based question...

I would like to see if anyone has any good recommendations on how to handle user- and project-based settings for devcontainers. What I mean by that is how to be able to use the Dockerfile and `devcontainer.json` set in the project and version controlled with added configuration based on user preferences. Examples are different environment variables, aliases or `bash_profile` definitions.

My approach would be to have them in a separated script invoked by "postCreateCommand", so every developer can have their own version locally, however this does not seem optimal at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: We ended up using a personalized dotfiles repository. They can be automatically checked out and installed by VS Code (using devcontainers or not).

Comment: Would love to hear more details on this...

Comment: @DouglasLudlow Here's a link on the subject: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_personalizing-with-dotfile-repositories